# VBA cannot loop through rows

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I have a piece of code that `loops` thru my `rows` in excel and find the first `character` of a `string` in a particular `column`. While that works perfectly with `i = i + 1` , when the first `condition` passed, it will then execute another action. Inside the action, sometime i have `errors` happening, thus i put `On error Handlers` so that i can move on to the next `row`. Here is the code that i have.

```
On Error GoTo errHandler
Check:
    While Cells(7 + i, 1).Value <> ""
        firstChar = Left(Cells(7 + i, 6).Value, 1)
        If firstChar = "A" Then
            .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nmm02"
            .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").Text = ""
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").Text = Cells(7 + i, 2)
            .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
            .findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
            .findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-LGTYP").Text = "AN1"
            .findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-LGTYP").SetFocus
            .findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-LGTYP").caretPosition = 3
            .findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP21/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB2:SAPLMGD1:2731/ctxtMLGN-PLKPT").Text = "AN1"
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP21/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB3:SAPLMGD1:2733/ctxtMLGN-LTKZA").Text = "AN1"
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP21/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB3:SAPLMGD1:2733/ctxtMLGN-LTKZE").Text = "AN1"
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP21/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB3:SAPLMGD1:2733/ctxtMLGN-LTKZE").SetFocus
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP21/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB3:SAPLMGD1:2733/ctxtMLGN-LTKZE").caretPosition = 3
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP22").Select
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP22/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB3:SAPLMGD1:2734/ctxtMLGT-LGPLA").Text = Cells(7 + i, 6)
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP22/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB3:SAPLMGD1:2734/ctxtMLGT-LGPLA").SetFocus
            .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP22/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB3:SAPLMGD1:2734/ctxtMLGT-LGPLA").caretPosition = 8
            .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
            .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/N"
            .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        ElseIf firstChar = "B" Then
             #another action
        ElseIf firstChar = "C" Then
             #another action
        Else:
        End If
        i = i + 1
errHandler:
    Cells(7 + i, 9).Value = "Error"
    session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n"
    GoTo Check
```

Basically, if there are no errors in between the actions, the `loop` works fine and go thru to another `rows`, if there is an `error`, `errHandler`'s action will be performed but it will goes back to `check:` and perform on the same `row` again. Also just to let everyone know, the `firstChar` that im searching for does not exist in every `row`, it can be on `row 10` and the next one will be `55th`.
Also, i tested by adding `i = i + 1` to `errHandler` and yes the first `error` was successfully avoided by going to the next `row`. However, if it meets another `error`, the same thing happens again, executing on the same `row`. Does it have anything to do with finding the `char` `'A'`,`'B'`,`'C'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error handler can only handle one error at a time.   Your handler was not reset so it is encountering the second error while still handling the first.

**The only way to reset the handler is by executing one of the following:**

- `Resume`
- `Exit Sub`
- `Exit Function`
- `Exit Property`
- `On Error Goto -1`

*Note that `Err.Clear` and `On Error Goto 0` will clear the error number but they will not reset the handier.  Also, `On Error Resume Next` is not the same as `Resume` (above) so it will not reset you handler either.*

**Your solution:**  replace `GoTo Check` with `Resume Check`

Using `Resume Check` will reset the handler and send execution to the `Label` just like your  `GoTo`.  This will also fix the infinite loop your `GoTo` appears to cause.  Presumably that code block should only be executed after raising an error so you may want to use `Exit Sub` or `Exit Function` above `errHandler:`.

Comment: Thanks! it worked now. btw, what do u mean by `Label`?

Comment: @JiaHao Wang Every `GoTo` has a `Label`, it is the receiving end of the `GoTo`. In VBA, it is the word that is always left justified and followed by a colon  ( : ).  You have two `Labels`, `Check:` and `errHandler:`

Comment: What if i have another error in the loop? how can i direct to another label and do another action?

Comment: @JiaHaoWang I've never seen seen that recommended.    Usually the suggestion is to rethink the strategy and either eliminate the need for the additional handler or to split the code off into a new function that contains the new handler.  That said, you can can use multiple `On Error` statements in a procedure, just remember that only one error can be active at any given time so you must be vary careful to ensure every error is reset before the you switch handlere.